# AJAX Success or error not firing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to figure out why this is not working or find a relevant article. I can see the json object in firebug return either success: false or success: true from the post request so i don't know why the function won't fire.

ajax

```
$("#login").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../process/login-process.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'username': $('[name=username]').val(), 'password': $('[name=password]').val() },
        beforeSend : function (){
            //$("#login").hide();       
        },
        success: function(data){
            window.localation=data.redirect;            
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $(".error").html('');
            alert('wtf');
            if(data.empty) {
                $(".error").html(data.empty);
            }
            if(data.incorrect) {
                $(".error").html(data.incorrect);
            }       
        }
    });
});
```

php

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include "../inc/connect.php";
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $password); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username ='$username' AND password ='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    if ($username == "" || $password == "") {
        $data['empty'] = 'All fields are required.';
    } else if(($count==1) && ($username)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['firstName']; 
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['adminID'];
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['redirect'] = '../pages/dashboard.php';
     } else { 
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['incorrect'] = "Incorrect Username or Password.";
     } 
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: check console for error messages.

Comment: `window.localation` ? this a typo?

Comment: try specifying `dataType:'Json'` in ajax request..and correct your typo instead of `window.localation` it should be `window.location`.

Comment: Are you sure the functions aren't firing? If you put breakpoints in them, does it stop when you get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending a string(in this case, a json) without any header mentioned. so it will always be 200 ok.

hence, error will never fire.

```
success: function(data){
        window.localation=data.redirect;   <----- error here. location         
    },
```

that's why nothing is happening.

**to fire the error in case data is incorrect**

instead of:

```
} else { 
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['incorrect'] = "Incorrect Username or Password.";
 }
```

use

```
} else { 
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password.';
    exit;
 }
```

this will give you a 403 forbidden message.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things which you need to correct in your code,

1. change `window.localation` to `window.location` in `success` callback
2. Add `dataType: 'JSON'` in ajax request or use `$.parseJSON` in success callback

So, your success callback should be:

```
success: function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data); // <- Don't use this if you add dataType: 'JSON' in ajax
            window.location=data.redirect;        //<- Spelling corrected for location    
        }
```